# Is there such a thing as inductive reasoning?

Tags: logic, induction, deduction

When I form hypotheses, don't I actually only use deduction instead of induction? Suppose I observe that the sun rises 5 days in a row, so I hypothesise that the sun rises every day.
But for this I am already using the theory that things that repeat themselves in the past will also repeat themselves in the future (Theory of uniformity).
So am I not really only using deduction?

Comment: That was Popper's interpretation of it, and the modern view is that it does not work, see [SEP, The Problem of Induction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/induction-problem/#LiviInduSkep). There are many hypotheses lying around, some even contradict each other, and we have limited resources to test too many. The question shifts to how we manage to hit upon the ones that work, or work after minor tweaks, as often as we do. Historical studies also showed that generation of hypotheses is not at all random, as Popper thought, and some kind of induction is already involved there.

Comment: @Conifold that sounds interesting, thanks! I Just thought about that "inductive reasoning" is in the end nothing more than deduction based on the nature of the mind?

So based on the experiences, processing, assumptions about the world made by brain itself? After one is born, the brain must be subject to some first underlying postulate in order to somehow classify sensory impressions.

Comment: @Conifold The brain is initially in an excited state after birth, to escape this one of the first things a newborn does is attention fixation, tracking events with the eyes. And somehow the theory of cause/effect might have developed deductively from this and everything else above it.

Comment: Whatever theories and experiences are developed, "deductively" or some other way, has to channel somehow into generating suitable hypotheses. And deduction tells us nothing on how it's done, new hypotheses are not deducible from old theories, or they wouldn't be new, or hypotheses. That's the problem of induction. See [Hanson, Is there a logic of scientific discovery?](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00048406085200111) for a classical critique of Popper and ideas on how it's done beyond deduction.

Comment: @Conifold 1/2: I think that one can deductively conclude new theories from old ones. Suppose after birth one of the first things that is based on the nature of the mind itself is to recognise cause/effect. That becomes the theory on which everything else is built, so maybe you can deductively deduce more, "you realise when you don't eat (cause) that you get hungry (effect) (and cause), so you start screaming (effect) to get food".

Comment: 2/2: Of course, with increasing complexity, nothing more can be deductively derived from a single theory later on, there comes the point at which several theories that one has formed through life experience (of course, initially only building on this one cause/effect postulate) are mixed and used together.

Comment: If you want to proceed "inductively", you try to abstract, but this abstracting follows patterns in each person (probably different ones), something is left out, generalised, but each of us has to start somewhere and you can only do that because of patterns already present in the brain, otherwise you wouldn't know how to approach it. So I think you always arrive at "new hypotheses" deductively, we call it inductive because it may be beyond the complexity we can imagine but it's basically very complex deductive reasoning, different deductive axioms are used for different aspects.

Comment: Inductive reasoning has a very distinct definition as opposed to deductive reasoning. You are thinking about Mathematical logic it seems because you think reasoning begins with axioms or assumptions. Math uses deduction but deductive reasoning has more than math. Inductive reasoning is about how we come to know our premises. Basically induction is reasoning that is not certain. There is a possibility of the conclusion being false. There is NO possibility of a sound deductive argument with true premises  being false. You can associate induction with percentage of accuracy. Deductions are 100 %.

Comment: The question would be "how did you come to the premise that the law of uniformity is true in the first place ?". This is also applies to the non temporal version of induction, like "all teenagers I met so far were horny, so this teenager I never met must be horny too".

Comment: I do not think you use ["deductive"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning) in the usual sense. It cannot produce anything new by definition, only logical consequences. Hypotheses are not logical consequences of what is known, they are guesses about the unknown. Complexity is irrelevant here. Einstein could not "deduce" special relativity from everything known before it, for example, even if he had deductive ability of infinite complexity.

Answer (score 0):

> Inductive reasoning is a method of reasoning in which a body of
> observations is synthesized to come up with a general principle. -wikipedia

What you are doing when you do some observation and form these observation go to a general principle is called induction as such. You can argue that because it uses the (1) priciple of uniforminty and (2) the observations, for some conclusion you are making some deductive reasoning. But this would no be true because the true premise that could give you a deductive reasoning would be like "Because the observation suggets X and principle of uniformity is true, then is probable than X happens" and no like "Bacuase the observations suggets x and principle of uniformity is true, then X is true". This is because the principle of uniformity just guarantees that is a probable true.